# Google Sheets API installation problem - quickstart.php not doing anything

Tags: php, api, ssh, google-sheets

I am trying to follow [this guide](http://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php) to connect my website to the Google Sheets API but there is a problem at step 4.

I connect to my website through SSH to access the console, enter the working directory where all the required files are stored with the "cd" command and then type the command "php quickstart.php" as per the guide, and nothing happens in the command line.

No result, no error, nothing, there is a new blank line waiting for a new command.

The only piece of evidence to help solve this mystery I have is a message I get when I open the PHP file in the browser (not the command line):

> Deprecated: google-api-php-client's autoloader was moved to vendor/autoload.php in 2.0.0. This redirect will be removed in 2.1. Please adjust your code to use the new location. in /home/*****/public_html/PHP/mailinglist/google-api-php-client/src/vendor/autoload.php on line 19
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: This application must be run on the
>   command line. in
>   /home/****/public_html/PHP/mailinglist/quickstart.php:5 Stack
>   trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   /home/****/public_html/PHP/mailinglist/quickstart.php on line 5

Any ideas on a fix? If it helps, my website is stored on a shared hosting managed by cPanel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try run script this way:
`php -d display_errors=on  quickstart.php`

maybe your php settings has disabled `display_errors` by default

Comment: Good idea! New result

`Deprecated: google-api-php-client's autoloader was moved to vendor/autoload.php in 2.0.0. This redirect will be removed in 2.1. Please adjust your code to use the new location. in /home/***/public_html/PHP/mailinglist/google-api-php-client/src/vendor/autoload.php on line 19

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google_Client' not found in /home/***/public_html/PHP/mailinglist/quickstart.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 /home/***/public_html/PHP/mailinglist/quickstart.php(63): getClient()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/***/public_html/PHP/mailinglist/quickstart.php on line 14`

Comment: probably this is the solution: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/992#issuecomment-233024164

Comment: Now when I actually look at the code inside "autoload.php" there doesn't seem to actually be anything to load the required files: [link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/autoload.php) - do you think I need to manually include all the files one by one?

Comment: no, if you are using composer then `autoload.php` should load all of your dependencies, do you get any errors now?

Comment: I am not using composer, I wanted to load it manually because I have not managed to figure out how to use composer with my hosting provider

Comment: The link you gave me is something I had already fixed before, the path was wrong but I have updated it accordingly

Comment: composer is mentioned in google tutorial as required, follow steps from here https://getcomposer.org/download/ and after installation run `php composer.phar install`

Comment: well in the link in the Step 2, it lists an alternative option to install in manually but apparently that does not work well, let me try to figure out how to install composer and if it doesn't help, I will start a new thread. thanks for your help though!